# express js only accepts 5 requests

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, http

i am using react and express in my project and I'm sending requests from my react client to my express server but when i try to perform a request to my expressjs API I can only perform 5 requests and the 6th and what's after it is denied

my react code:

```
fetch('http://localhost:9000/searchprocessor', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({
                product: {
                  Searchinput: e.target.value
                } 
            })
        });
```

(fetching a request every time "e.target.value" changes)

now handling the request in express:

```
  router.post('/', function(request, response){ 

  fs.readFile('./processes/itemrequested.json', function readFileCallback(err, data, next) {
  if (err){
    console.log(err);
 } else {
 var content = JSON.parse(data); //covert it to an object


var reqproduct = request.body.product.Searchinput;
console.log("in searchprocessor requested product is: " + reqproduct);
 content.item = reqproduct;
 console.log("in searchprocessor content.item is: " + content.item);

 json = JSON.stringify(content, null, 4); //convert it back to json
 console.log(json)
 fs.writeFile('./processes/itemrequested.json', json, 'utf8', (callback) => {
  console.log("searchprocessor callback: " + callback);
  }); // write it back 
  }});
 });
```

a simple code editing the content of itemrequested.json which contains:

```
{"item": ""  }
```

when logging the variable (reqproduct) it logs and works perfectly fine until I send the 6th request, for example:
sending 5 requests the first containing the number 1 all the way to the fifth request which contains the number 5 and then when send the 6th request(which for example contains the number 6) nothing happens the server stops working.
that's my problem i hope something can help me I've been stuck with it for 3days and i can't find a solution

Comment: there is no `response.send()`. How are you getting the response even in the 1st time

Comment: @aRvi im not sending a response, im just logging the request

Comment: try sending the response and check if the 6th request works

Comment: @aRvi i get your point but i don't need to, because even if the logging stops at the fifth request, also the (itemrequested.json)'s "item" can only be changed 5 times once every request

Comment: You need to actually terminate the requests, this is because you're hitting the limit for the number of pending requests you can have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is caused by the browser.  The browser has a limit for how many requests it will send to the same host at once and beyond that, the requests are queued in the browser until one of the prior requests finishes.

Each browser implements this slightly differently, but the limit is generally around 5 requests to the same host.

Some sites work around this by actually having multiple hostnames that map to the same server and using different requests to different hostnames to get around the limit.

In all cases, it's best to rethink your API design so that you don't need as many requests (try combining multiple requests into one larger request, for example).

Also, make sure you are sending a proper response to every single request on your server.  If you don't send a response, then those requests will hang out for awhile until they eventually timeout.  The `router.post()` code you show does not send any response.  It at least needs a `res.send("")` or `res.end()` if you don't need any actual response data.

Comment: your absolutely right, because when I refresh my browser I can perform the 5 requests again.
thank you so much !

Comment: @MiladDeraawi - See what I added to my answer.

Comment: @MiladDeraawi - Also see my latest addition to the answer that may be partly causing your problem.  You must send a response to ever request or they don't finish for a long time (until they eventually timeout) - making your problem at lot worse.